# 500 Internal server error/ js to controller

Tags: javascript, c#

Hello I have always the message 500 (Internal Server Error).
I am trying to call a function in the controller via js file. I already did the same logic in another project but here it is not working.

**here the function in controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetJqGridData(PagingCriteria pagingCriteria, SearchBaseCriteria searchCritiria)
        {
            var pagingResult = _SalesContract.GetPagedResult(pagingCriteria, searchCritiria);
            var jqGridData = new JqGridObject()
            {
                Data = pagingResult.Items,
                Page = pagingCriteria.PageNo,
                PageSize = pagingCriteria.MaximumNoOfItemsPerPage,
                SortColumn = pagingCriteria.OrderByPropertyName,
                SortOrder = pagingCriteria.OrderByDirection.ToString(),
                Total = pagingResult.TotalCount,
                TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)pagingResult.TotalCount / pagingCriteria.MaximumNoOfItemsPerPage)
            };
            return Json(jqGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**I want to call this function from js.**

```
   _grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            //url: UnAppUrl,
            url: '/SalesContract/GetJqGridData',
            mtype: 'POST',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "Data", //array containing actual data
                repeatitems: false,
                total: 'TotalPages',
                records: 'Total',
                page: 'Page',
                id: "SalesI
```

thanks for your help

Comment: This looks like C#, not VB.net

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question. First it is c# not vb.net. We have no clue what _SalesContract_GetPagedResult does. Maybe debug into the method. Make a breakpoint at the first line and make a call with Postman or smth similar. You also dont mention what kind of webapi you use (Mvc5?)

Comment: You may be able to find more useful details of the error in the Windows event logs on the web server.

Comment: Yes sorry  it is c#.. my problem is that the controller's function is not been called.. i tried to debug into the method but the system dont call it..

Comment: There may be an issue during model binding for PagingCriteria pagingCriteria or SearchBaseCriteria searchCritiria.